# Iperf TCP test variations

Tags: tcp, iperf

I am using iperf to test the connection between two machines (WiFi+AP), one runs Ubuntu14, and the other is Win7. Both are on the same subnet.

The problem is that the results varies very much over time, and varies from run to run! and I couldn't figure out the exact reasons?

results snip:

```
[  4] local 192.168.0.135 port 5001 connected with 192.168.0.147 port 42003 
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth 
[  4]  0.0- 5.0 sec  2.77 MBytes  4.64 Mbits/sec 
[  4]  5.0-10.0 sec  3.68 MBytes  6.17 Mbits/sec 
[  4] 10.0-15.0 sec  3.42 MBytes  5.74 Mbits/sec 
[  4] 15.0-20.0 sec  1.23 MBytes  2.07 Mbits/sec 
[  4] 20.0-25.0 sec  1.10 MBytes  1.85 Mbits/sec 
[  4] 25.0-30.0 sec  1.04 MBytes  1.74 Mbits/sec 
[  4] 30.0-35.0 sec  1.51 MBytes  2.54 Mbits/sec
```

command @ Win Server

> iperf -c IP -i 5 -t 60

Command @ Ub Client

> iperf -s -i 5

Could anyone help me explaining why it varies that much? and how to correctly probe the connection between the two machines for later comparisons?

Answer (score 0):

Your results draw expected variation.

Anyway, this fluctuation would be due to different factors:

1. Network traffic. Are those nodes alone on the switch/router/network or they are influenced by other nodes?
2. Processors traffic. Are you running processes/services/daemons that may slow down your processors so that your processor may lag your transmission?

Indeed, several factors would be behind.

Comment: So, These Variations are expected?
I saw a snapshot on a tutorial, and the results were almost identical (+-.01Mbps).
1) I'm using the network on times when almost no other users may be using it, but not guaranteed. But in all runs, huge variations like this exists.
Also, may the many other WiFi networks coexist in the same region be a reason?
2) I'm not using the machines during the test.
Any suggestions?